# Differential Equations of Infinite Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As a physicist I was playing with some QM problem and stumbled upon an ordinary differential equation of infinite order (coefficients are polynomials) that could be cast in the form:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n0}+a_{n1}x + a_{n2}x^2 + ... + a_{np}x^p)u^{(n)}(x) = 0$

After a little bit of searching I came across papers by H.T.Davis and L.Carleson that deal with variations of this problem (those papers are from the 30s or 40s).
I was wondering whether there are newer results and where I could find them (maybe a more general theory?).

Comment: Would you mind linking to those papers you say you found?

Comment: Even if Lennart Carleson (born 1928) is undoubtedly a genius, I have difficulties believing that he wrote papers in the 30s and 40s.

Comment: Sorry, the [paper by Carleson](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1356) is obviously from 1953.

The papers I found by Davis:
[Differential Equations of Infinite Order with Constant Coefficients](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1968313)
[The Laplace Differential Equation of Infinite Order](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2370650)